# Write a shell script to keep reconnecting SSH for proxy when the connection is lost

Tags: linux, shell, networking, ssh, proxy

I have a server for SSH proxy. 
Usually, I connect to the server like this:

```
ssh proxy-server -D 7070
```

However, my network is not stable and I often lose the connection to the proxy-server. Then I have to switch to Terminal and type this command again...

I was wondering whether I could write a script, so that it could try to make the connection again when it detects the connection to the proxy-server is lost. But I don't know how to detect whether the connection is lost periodically. Anyone has ideas about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can wait till ssh exits and put it in a loop:

```
while true
do
   ssh -TN $1 -D 7070
done
```

But Florin is right this don't mean that your connection is operational, a hang could still block your ssh command and you don't really know.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I think you can detect if a network resource is still available is by sending data to it. What you could do is have daemon that keeps pinging the proxy-server every 2-3s. As soon as it detects lost connectivity, make it run a script that launches a terminal straight into a ssh connection to the proxy-server (or keep trying to, until the proxy becomes available). Maybe there are more elegant ways, but I can't think of any.